# how to parse a file and transfer a set of two pairwise data into a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, parsing, hashmap

I have a file after parse it using following code

```
with open ('cl1_vs_cl1.blast', 'rb') as csvfile:
read= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='|')                    
for row in read:
print row[0],row[1],row[11]
```

it will generate a file like

```
A B = n1
A C = n2
A D = n3
B C = n4
B D = n5
......
```

i would like to assign the pairwised data into a 2D array.

```
  A B C D .....
A   n1 n2 n3
B n1    
C n2 n4
D n3 n5 .......
```

How can i achieve it?
if I also want to save the pairwised data as a hash of hashs in perl  how i suppose to do it?
Thanks a lot!

...

Comment: Do you want the keys to be in the array? Meaning, do you want the element at array[0][1] to be 'A' or n1?

Comment: for the hash i would like the A ,B to be the key ...like map of maps in the c++ map<string, map <string, string> >  for the array,I am not sure if it matters? .i am plan to use the array to build a hierarchy clustering for these elements A, B, C, D......

Comment: sorry for confusion, that A, B ,C, D, only stand for elements. in my case it usually would be 2000-50000 elements input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the hash part (also known as a dictionary in python)

```
from collections import defaultdict
myHash = defaultdict(defaultdict) # dictionary
for row in read:
    myHash[row[0]][row[1]] = row[11]
```

This will give allow you to access your info by myHash['A']['B'] and get back n1

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think i it a right approach for the hash